# How configure roundcube to work with imaps?

Tags: email-server, imap, roundcube

I recently installed Postfix, Dovecot to setup a mail server on my own VPS ( using this tutorial: [Email with Postfix, Dovecot, Mysql](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql))

Imaps server uses port 993 for Authentication, and Postfix uses port 25 to send mails.
In this tutorial, users stored in a Database ( so imaps use mysql to authenticate users).
i'm sure every thing works fine with imaps and postfix , because few days ago i installed Kmail client (on my linux) and receive mails from my server. sending mails also works fine, i sent a mail to Gmail and google received it without a problem (in my "Gmail inbox" not spam folder)

So to get to my Emails from a web mail client, i installed [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) on */var/www/mail* directory.

I configured Roundcube many times. but each time it gives me this Error:

> IMAP Error: Login failed for [me@mydomain] from X.x.X.x . Empty
>   startup greeting (localhost:993) in
>   /var/www/mm/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184 (POST
>   /mm/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)

When i do log in from roundcube, imap server says ( in */var/log/mail.log* ):

> May 20 07:05:16 my-server dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth
>   attempts): rip=::1, lip=::1, TLS handshaking: Disconnected

Here is my roundcube config file :

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcubeuser:myPassword@localhost/roundcubemail';
// ----------------------------------
// IMAP
// ----------------------------------
$config['debug_level'] = 13;
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://127.0.0.1';
$config['default_port'] = 993;
// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------
$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://localhost';
```

What's the problem? i really have no idea what is happening !

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In my config :

```
$config['default_host'] = 'imaps://domain.tld';

// TCP port used for IMAP connections
$config['default_port'] = 993;
```

I know that it is not the doc, but it is working. Think about certificate : it should be compliant with your domain.tld

Comment: no that imaps://domain.tld doesn't work.

i'm confused! what about certificate? what did u mean?

Comment: 'imaps' string was also include for comparability for `ssl` string, it defined in [this line of code](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/216b31dd99b54e7be3df8feebeafae72e423bb1c/program/include/rcmail.php#L533).

Comment: This solved my problem with Roundcubemail 1.1.3 on CentOS 7. Thank you.

Comment: It's taken me two days f&$%ing with `tls://` to find this answer, you've saved my hair, thank you!

Comment: this actually saved my day too. not documented on roundcube side but works for 1.3.4 too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467819/roundcube-wont-connect-to-imaps-port-993

Answer (score 7):

once i have problem with one of my mail servers i use these in **dovecot.conf** :

```
auth_verbose=yes
auth_debug=yes
auth_debug_passwords=yes
mail_debug=yes
verbose_ssl=yes
auth_verbose_passwords=plain
```

then use:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

you will see everything that is going on behind the scene..